# Grow up Animation for layout in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to do an animation when clicking on a button another layout that will appear which look like growing from inside the button.I coudnt find any tutorial or any clue..Please help me.

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="8"

Comment: in that case use a ScaleAnimation, check out answer below

Answer (score 1):

use a `ScaleAnimation` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html

this is the Constructor you'll need:

```
public ScaleAnimation (float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY)
```

So do something like:

```
ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(0f, 1f, 0f, 1f);
anim.setDuration(700)//milliseconds
anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){
...
});
myLayout.startAnimation(anim);
```

you you can add an AnimationListener to it and set your layout visible atAnimationEnd()